# Convert Android xml layout to png/svg for iOS

Tags: android, ios, xml, svg, png

An Android `layout/*.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/locationMarker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/locationMarkertext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_map"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minWidth="180dp"
            android:onClick="create"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:text="Pick the Location"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:onClick="create"
            android:src="@drawable/plus" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

renders looking like this:

[image: Pin layout xml screenshot]

I want to reuse that for iOS. Can that be exported to other formats (`.svg`, `.png`, etc) that allows re-use without re-creation? It needs transparency and `.svg` seems preferable to `.png`. I'd like only the displayed visible part to be clickable too.

Comment: This newer question links multiple relevant webapps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62540139/convert-android-vector-drawable-xml-to-svg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent technology in iOS is Apple's **"autolayout" system**.

It's quite easy to use once you get the hang of it; the fact is though like anything it's a specialist thing.  And sure, you could just make a transparent PNG and use that as an image for a UIButton.

I would really suggest just using a "UIButton" in Apple, and play with the colors etc until you get a look that is OK -- **although not identical to the other platform**.

The two key points are

1. it's almost impossible, technically, to make apps look identical on different platforms
2. pretty much everyone agrees you should not try to do that; other than in games, allow elements like buttons etc. to be "natural" on each platform / os version.

BTW I have no idea why anyone would downvote your question. Cross-platform issues are one of the most critical in development today.

Comment: I think it's being downvoted because the answer to the question asked is "No" and could have been found by a quick Google search. (I did not downvote)

Comment: How can the answer be completely "no"? I was thinking at the very least I could crop the screenshot I took, edit it in photoshop, and use that as the image for the UIButton. I was just wondering if there were better ways because I couldn't find anything better online.

Comment: Read the third sentence of the answer; it explains how to do it just as you say with a PNG -> "UIButton"