# How do I export Android XML vector drawables to another format?

Tags: android, xml, vector, png

I want to recreate my app for iOS and the icons in Android are XML vectors with the "android:pathData" attribute. How do I convert these to an image that I can place into Xcode and use (preserving transparency)?

I have searched for a solution and found nothing and read the article on the Android Developer site on Vector Asset Studio but found nothing about exporting these drawables to something I can import into Xcode.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Android xml layout to png/svg for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613887/convert-android-xml-layout-to-png-svg-for-ios)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did it by creating an SVG file and copying the value of the pathData attribute of the path element in the XML file and pasting it into the d attribute of the path element in the SVG file. I then converted it to PNG using ImageMagick.

So

```
<path android:pathData="[Path Data]">
```

becomes

```
<path d="[Path Data]">.
```

Then

```
convert -background none image.svg image.png
```

in the command line.

If there is a better way of doing this please post it.

Comment: The problem here would be that iOS needs a lot of variants of the app icon depending if it is 1x, 2x, or even 3x resolution, and there are different sizes for iPhone, iPad, and iPad Pro. Plus there is the version that will show up in a search box, etc.... so at the least you'll have to provide an output size in the conversion.

Comment: What about android:fillColor attribute ? What is its counterpart for SVG?

Comment: @zulkarnainshah it's `fill`. for example, `fill="red"`.

Answer (score -1):

After using the trick Questioner provide, I use a browser to open the svg file, zoom-in to the size as big as possible and take a screenshot. FYI.